# Mathematical demonstration of the distance concentration in high dimensions

Tags: probability-theory, machine-learning, dimensional-analysis, concentration-of-measure

I know that in high-dimensional space, the distance between almost all pairs of points has almost the same value ("Distance Concentration"). See [Aggarwal et al. 2001, On the Surprising Behavior of Distance Metrics in High Dimensional Space](https://bib.dbvis.de/uploadedFiles/155.pdf).

Is there a mathematical way to observe this phenomenon?

Comment: Not clear to me what you mean by "a mathematical way to observe" something.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, simply I mean a mathematical equation

Comment: I see lots of equations in the paper you link to. Won't one of them do?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, simply, I understand the following statement "the distance between almost all pairs of points has almost the same value (Distance Concentration)", but I want to comprehend this statement by a mathematical representation.

Comment: And that's not done in the paper you cite?

Comment: You posted the same question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/451027/mathematical-demonstration-of-the-distance-concentration-in-high-dimensions without linking the two questions to each other. That's a serious abuse of these websites. How many other places have you posted your question?

Comment: https://www.computer.org/csdl/journal/tk/2017/02/07723906/13rRUwI5Ugw